# Wrong output size when plotting over an image in R

Tags: r, image, plot, png, jpeg

My goal is to read an image file in either the PNG or JPEG format and plot various data over said image and save it to disk.

I also want the image to take up all available space in the produced plot, no axes or labels or anything. I'm a bit concerned that this might be relevant to my problem.

### Code example

Below is my current code that currently only tries to output the same image as you put in. Later I plan on plotting data points corresponding to coordinates over the image. I've used some sample code found here in order to remove the axes and be able to have the image in the background of the plot.

```
library(jpeg)
library(grid)

img <- readJPEG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg"),native=TRUE)
jpeg(filename = "Rlogo-2.jpg", width=100,height=76, quality = 100,res=299)

op<-par(mar=rep(0,4))
plot(0:100,type="n", axes="FALSE",ann="FALSE")
lim <- par()
rasterImage(img, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])

dev.off()
```

### Example output

This is an example output of my above code in a comparison with the original image:

[image]

The image to the left is the original and the right one is the modified one. As you can see it seems as if the image I read and plot somehow is smaller than the original image and when saved to the original dimensions it appears blurred.

I've been pulling my hair over this one for hours and I don't seem to get anywhere. This is my first attempt to plot data over images and I'm aware of my lack of knowledge about how R represents images and I've mostly been using the basic graphics to do relatively simple plots before.

I'm currently considering doing this in Python instead but I'm afraid that'll come back and bite me when it comes to the actual plotting of the data.

I run R version 3.1.0 on x86_64 running Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize, since you already found the culprit, there are two issues present here:

Firstly, the blurring appears to be caused by the `jpeg` device on Windows. There is no such problem on Ubuntu Linux and it disappears if you use the Cairo-device instead, as you did already discover. Cairo-devices are great for pdf:s too since they embed all the fonts etc. making the figure look the same across platforms.

Secondly, R adds 4% extra margin to the x and y axes by default to prevent graphics from being chopped off near the edge of the plot area. It can be corrected by setting `xaxs="i"` and `yaxs="i"`.

```
par(mfrow=1:2)
plot(1:5, 1:5) # Left
plot(1:5, 1:5, xaxs="i", yaxs="i") # Right
```

[image]

In your case the difference is subtle but still would cause everything to be slightly misaligned.

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful @Backlin, I had no idea about this plotting mechanic. However I can't seem to reproduce your result. I can reproduce the two plots in your example illustrating the difference between "r" and "i" just fine, however I still get the slightly blurred and misaligned R logo when I run my code example with your suggested additions to plot(). Starting to suspect the computer being cursed. Will try on another machine to see if I get the same result, alternatively another computer architecture.

Comment: Are you running R on Windows? I posted the answer after testing it on my linux computer at work, but now noticed that it doesn't work on my Windows home computer. There is however a way to hack around it by first writing the foreground plot to a file and then manually combine it with the background picture (see [alpha compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) on wikipedia), but I got the code at work and can update tomorrow.

Comment: As I suspected: black magic. I do indeed run R on Windows, I will update my question with OS details and R version information. This is great though, now we get to have both the solution for linux and Windows in the same place! I suspected that Windows might'be been the culprit since I read in some other R graphics documentation that certain things didn't work on Windows. I'm limited to running Windows at the moment and would greatly appreciate your glorious hack!

Comment: This issue kept lurking in the back of my head all evening... I kept poking at the graphics output and found that by using `type="cairo"` in the `jpeg()` function produced the correct non-distorted image output on Windows.
The issue that you answered is perhaps not so obviously illustrated in my example since I didn't plot any actual data points to keep it about the output but it is an essential part of what I'm trying to achieve. It would've been my next hurdle, wondering why, oh why, the plot didn't extend all the way to the edges of the image.